# Simpler way of performing Gaussian Elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

Is there a simpler way of performing Gaussian Elimination other than using [RowReduce](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html)? Such as a single built in function?

**Edit:**
 Look at the example from our simulation class. Not too difficult, but using this method to solve problems of the sort is new to most of us. We are solving for P# of course.
[image: Example]

Also, to those asking... While I can see what is going on below, I really don't understand what it all means. Asking why not RowReduce? I guess not everyone is at that level of use yet, and I don't like just cutting and pasting internet code without understanding it. I simply wondered if there was a function that would do what the code did, but be built in.

```
  GaussianElimination[m_?MatrixQ, v_?VectorQ] :=
    Last /@ RowReduce[Flatten /@ Transpose[{m, v}]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `RowReduce`? How is it not satisfactory and what do you mean by "simpler" solution?

Comment: Do you mean LinearSolve?

Comment: If you just need to solve an equation, use `LinearSolve`, no need for implementing a specific method.  If you need the specific method, then what R.M. said.

Comment: Simpler, like a function versus having to device my own. I will look at LinearSolve, but might just use RowReduce.

Comment: Hola 'los, what are you looking for exactly? In other words, how do you plan on using it the results?

Comment: I was trying to device a way to check my answers for a reservoir simulation class. Basically, see the pressures as they fall away from the reservoir. Currently we use excel, but I wanted something nicer.

Comment: Could you fill in some of the mathematical details in you question, then we could better direct you to the function you should use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based upon your update, you are trying to solve the system

$$\mathbf{A}\vec{x} = \vec{b}$$

for $\vec{x}$, so [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html) is exactly what you want. Also, it has the exact form

```
LinearSolve[A, b]
```

that you're asking for. Internally it uses a form of Gaussian elimination to solve such systems; this is most likely a variant of [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), but other [methods](http://wolfram.com/xid/0e7qe9wi-elbw9t) are available. If you have more than one $\vec{b}$, you can use the form

```
solv = LinearSolve[A]
```

which returns a [`LinearSolveFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolveFunction.html) which you can apply to each $\vec{x}$ in turn via

```
solv[b]
```

**Edit**:  In the case of your example, [`RowReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RowReduce.html) will return the identity matrix as your matrix is invertible (non-singular), so it would not be immediately useful. You could make it "useful" and create an augmented matrix, via

```
 augA = ArrayFlatten[{{#, IdentityMatrix[Length@#]}}]& @ A
```

which creates $$\left(\mathbf{A}\, |\, \mathbf{I} \right).$$ Then,

```
 redAugA = RowReduce[augA]
```

gives a matrix of the form $$\left(\mathbf{I}\, |\, \mathbf{A}^{-1} \right),$$ and the inverse is extractable via

```
redAugA[[All, Length@A + 1 ;; ]]
```

which uses the shorthand form of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) to extract only the columns you want. But, if your going to go to the trouble of getting the inverse, you might as well use [`Inverse[A]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inverse.html) directly.

However, if your matrix is singular, i.e. `MatrixRank[A] < Length[A]`, then you need to use [`LeastSquares`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeastSquares.html) which returns the vector, $\vec{x}$, that minimizes $\lVert\mathbf{A}\vec{x} - \vec{b}\rVert_2$ where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ refers to the standard Euclidean norm. Which has the same calling convention

```
LeastSquares[A, b]
```

but it lacks the pre-calculation capabilities of `LinearSolve`. If you need those, then you would first decompose the matrix using [`QRDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/QRDecomposition.html) and then [`LinearSolve`](http://wolfram.com/xid/09cmhdv2a-bxgway) is used, as follows

```
{q,r} = QRDecomposition[A];
LinearSolve[r, q.b]
```

Or, if you want a single function that operates like the second form of `LinearSolve` but with the least squares minimization,

```
savedLeastSquares[m_?MatrixQ]:= 
 Module[{q,r}, 
  {q,r} = QRDecomposition[m];
  LinearSolve[r, q.#]&
 ]
```

Comment: One could also use `SingularValueDecomposition[]` instead of `QRDecomposition[]`...

Comment: Your same idea of augmentation can be used to solve for A.x=b: instead of augmenting by an identity matrix, put b in a new (rightmost) column. Example: `In[50]:= A = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {4, 4}];
b = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 4];
LinearSolve[A, b] - 
 RowReduce[ArrayFlatten[{{#, Transpose[{b}]}}] &@A][[All, -1]]

Out[52]= {0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau absolutely, where do you think I got the idea?